# "Size or zero" of value of multivalued hashmap

Tags: java, collections, hashmap

I have a multivalued `Hashmap` (technically a `LinkedHashMap`):

```
private LinkedHashMap<String, ArrayList<BodyPart>> bodyParts  = new LinkedHashMap<>();
```

I want to find the number of values associated with a given key.  However, `bodyParts.get("sample key")` returns `null` if the key isn't present, whereas I want it to return 0 (as there are zero values associated with that key).

I could shield it in an `if` statement:

```
int numberOfValues;
if(bodyParts.containsKey("sample"){
    numberOfValues = bodyParts.get("sample").size();
}
```

but I was wondering if there is an easier/better way to do it?  I've read the documentation for `computeIfPresent` but, truthfully, didn't really understand it.

Comment: Instead of `LinkedHashMap<String, ArrayList<BodyPart>>` you could use a Guava's `Multimap` - `get()` always returns a collection, empty one if there are no values.

Comment: I did see that, but I can't - receiving the `LinkedHashMap` from an external source and transferring it seems like a long way round.  Thanks though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Map.getOrDefault(Object key, V defaultValue)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#getOrDefault-java.lang.Object-V-).

> Returns the value to which the specified `key` is mapped, or `defaultValue` if this map contains no mapping for the key.

Comment: Just to mention this here: The "default value" should in this case be a `Collections.emptyList()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `getOrDefault` method of Java [Map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) interface.

It allows you to set default value that is to be returned in case value corresponding to key is not found. So in use case mentioned above you can use : 
 `numberOfValues = bodyParts.getOrDefault("sample", new ArrayList<BodyPart>()).size();`

Comment: Instead of `new ArrayList<BodyPart>()`, it should be `Collections.emptyList()`. You don't always want to create a new list instance just to obtain the (constant, 0) size of it.